# tabu environment giving an error

Tags: tabu

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{Test Data for Liquid limit, this are the measurements necessary that we needed to get in order to calculate the moisture content of our soil sample.}
    \begin{tabu}{*{5}{x[c]}}
        \toprule
         \textbf{Property} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Test 1} & \textbf{Test 2} & \textbf{Test 3}  \\
         \midrule
         Blows & - & 25 & 17 & 15 \\
         Oven Can ID & - & Red #2 & Green #2 & Yellow #2 \\
         Mass of Oven Can & g/lb & 62.78 & 62.68 & 62.65 \\
         Mass of Oven Can and Wet Soil & g/lb & 75.24 & 78.48 & 77.68 \\
         Mass of Oven Can and Dry Soil & g/lb & 73.3 & 76 & 75.3 \\
         \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
    \label{tab:measurements}
\end{table}
```

Comment: tabu does not work and is unsupported sorry, it was abandoned some years ago by its maintainer (but please when posting examples always make them complete small documents and say what error you got, don't make people guess how to test your fragment)

Comment: but you have errors unrelated to tabu, you need `Red \#2` if you intend the text **Red #2** and the column is `X` not `x` with those changes it gives no error, but don't use `tabu`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors: `x` in the column specification should be `X` and `#` in the body should be escaped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\caption{Test Data for Liquid limit, this are the measurements necessary 
that we needed to get in order to calculate the moisture content of our soil sample.}
\label{tab:measurements}

\begin{tabu}{*{5}{X[c]}}
\toprule
\textbf{Property} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Test 1} & \textbf{Test 2} & \textbf{Test 3} \\
\midrule
Blows & -- & 25 & 17 & 15 \\
Oven Can ID & - & Red \#2 & Green \#2 & Yellow \#2 \\
Mass of Oven Can & g/lb & 62.78 & 62.68 & 62.65 \\
Mass of Oven Can and Wet Soil & g/lb & 75.24 & 78.48 & 77.68 \\
Mass of Oven Can and Dry Soil & g/lb & 73.3 & 76 & 75.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The `\label` should be next to (or inside) `\caption`, this is not an error, but this way it is more logical. Also `[h!]` is wrong.

[image]

However, there are two remarks:

1. the output is not really attractive: the first column, in particular, is really bad;
2. the `tabu` package works in some cases (such as this one), but it's buggy and unmaintained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering

\caption{Test Data for Liquid limit, this are the measurements necessary 
that we needed to get in order to calculate the moisture content of our soil sample.}
\label{tab:measurements}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Property} & \textbf{Unit} & \textbf{Test 1} & \textbf{Test 2} & \textbf{Test 3} \\
\midrule
Blows & -- & 25 & 17 & 15 \\
Oven Can ID & -- & Red \#2 & Green \#2 & Yellow \#2 \\
Mass of Oven Can & g/lb & 62.78 & 62.68 & 62.65 \\
Mass of Oven Can and Wet Soil & g/lb & 75.24 & 78.48 & 77.68 \\
Mass of Oven Can and Dry Soil & g/lb & 73.3 & 76 & 75.3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The standard classes are set up for captions below tables; if you use a different class, it might be set for captions above tables, otherwise, load `caption` or move the caption where it's expected to be.

With `tabular*`, which is a standard environment, there is no need to split the entries in the first column across lines.

Instead of the hyphen to denote missing data, an en-dash is better.